# Completeness of n-(finitely)-Valued Gödel Logic w.r.t IPC+Linearity+$F_n$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

n-Valued Gödel Logic is apparently complete with respect to IPC with the added axioms of Linearity:

$(A \rightarrow B) \lor (B \rightarrow A)$

and $F_n$:

$\bigvee_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (A_i \leftrightarrow A_j)$

I have managed to figure out how to do the soundness proof between the n-valued Gödel Logic and this deductive system, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do the completeness proof.